# WCF service interface inheritance

Tags: web-services, wcf, inheritance

I have got WCF Service which has several interfaces implemented.  Interfaces inherit from the base interface.

```
public interface IServiceA : IBaseService

public interface IServiceB : IBaseService
```

In the process of publishing, is it possible to hide one or more interfaces and expose only one selected?

Comment: Why does IServiceA extend IBaseService if you want want to expose IBaseService?

Comment: I want to expose IServiceA  in one case and in second case I want to expose IServiceB.

Comment: Oh, should be easy. There must be a point where you specify which interface you expose. Likely the .config bindings section.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/configuring-multiple-end-points-for-wcf-service/